# How to pass different directives to the same modal

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog

I want a modal to display a single input text field but with different directive attached to that input.

Inside my modal component:

```
<input directive>
```

I would call the modal in two different ways i.e :

```
this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  width: '250px',
  data: {directive: MyDirective1}
});

this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {directive: MyDirective2}
});
```

Is this behavior achievable ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to set a directive as modal dialog data.

The used directives should be in the "declarations" of your module. In this case you can use the directive(s) in the modal component template.

You can set some flags in the modal data if you need informations from 'outside'.

Comment: Okay so pass a variable for instance then based on the variable load a different directive ?